# Strange memory leak by leakcanary in WebView Android

Tags: android, webview, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I used leakcanary to detect my app memory and found a leak of an Activity which contains a webview. When I deleted the code about WebView, it detected no leak. However, when adding the code of webview, leakcanary showed a very strange message like this [leak message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/543jb.jpg). It showed a leak caused by TextToSpeech but indeed I didn't use this class. I'm sure that the leak is caused by WebView, so I google the problem and find it seems to be a "famous" leak in Android. I have tried many solutions but none of them could work. This is the code about WebView in my FaceWebViewActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_face_webview);

    webContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.webview_container);

    webView = new WebView(this);
    webView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    webContainer.addView(webView);

    // 初始化网页浏览器
    webView.requestFocus();
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    webView.loadUrl(URL);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:faceDraw()");
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    RefWatcher refWatcher = BaseApplication.getRefWatcher(this);
    refWatcher.watch(this);
    if (webView != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) webView.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.removeView(webView);
        }
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(null);
        webView.setWebViewClient(null);
        webView.setTag(null);
        webView.clearHistory();
        webView.removeAllViews();
        webView.destroy();
        webView = null;
    }
}
```

I initialized a WebView in Java code and didn't add it in xml. In the destroy function I removed it from the view hierarchy, but leakcanary still showd that leak message(I'm sure I didn't use TextToSpeech in my code). 
Did someone get the same leak message like me? Could you please tell me some tips about that message and help me get rid of it.

Comment: I hope this line must help you to get out of this leak if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) // KITKAT
        {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

Comment: Thanks for your help! But it still leaks :(